# iptables forward incoming ipv4 traffic to ipv6

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, forwarding

I am new to iptables and I am lost and confused from its configuration. 
I have work server with IPv4 and IPv6 connection and the home server with only IPv6 connection.

How to set up rules for forwarding all incoming IPv4 traffic, port 5600 from work server to my home server (IPv6 address), port 5600?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, you just can't. Transports are different, iptables can't do that. However, you can setup a process that will suck data from a socket and feed it into another.

You can try that on your work server :

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:5600,fork,su=nobody TCP6:[home_server_ipv6_address]:5600
```

Good luck.